# Postgres - full table scan too slow - index is not being used

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I have a table in a postgres database with many columns, among which I have:

```
n_store_object_id     integer,
n_latitude            decimal,
n_longitude           decimal
```

The table has about 250,000 rows at present.

I need to find records with non-null store_object_id located within a fixed distance from a given location.  For distance computation, I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_geo_distance(numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
declare
    lat1d       ALIAS for $1;
    lon1d       ALIAS for $2;
    lat2d       ALIAS for $3;
    lon2d       ALIAS for $4;

    lat1        DECIMAL := lat1d / 57.29577951;
    lon1        DECIMAL := lon1d / 57.29577951;
    lat2        DECIMAL := lat2d / 57.29577951;
    lon2        DECIMAL := lon2d / 57.29577951;
begin
    return 3963.0 * acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 - lon1));
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Now, the query I would require is simple:

```
select *
  from objects
 where n_store_object_id is not null
   and fn_geo_distance(51.5, 0, n_latitude, n_longitude) <= 20
```

This takes quite a long time - and when I "explain" this query, I can see a full table scan.  Fair enough.  So I create an index on these three columns:

```
create index idx_object_location on objects(n_store_object_id, n_latitude, n_longitude)
```

I re-run the query above - and it still takes a long time.  "Explaining" it shows that the newly created index is not being used.  Am I missing something?  Why is it not used and how can I force the engine to use it? Oh, and first of all, would this index even help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your index orders by ID, then lat, then long.  That won't help because it can't figure out a range of IDs to search for.

You can not index this well using conventional "btree" indexes (the default in postgres and every other sql).  If you think about the problem for a moment, most indexes are based on ordering things (numerically or alphabetically).  But you can not order geography.  You can order things in order of their distance from a single point, but when you move that point, some things will be closer, others will be further so the order changes.

**Best...**
There are special indexes created for this problem.  Since you're using postgres, I suggest you read up on GiST.  http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html (please google as well as following this link).

This is now included as part of postgres and is specifically designed for handling geography.

**Alternativly...**
The secondary solution is to place TWO indexes on the data, one latitute (only) one logditude (only).  And add a max and min lat and long to the query as mentioned in another answer.  Postgres can use BOTH indexes togeather to narrow down. It is important that you use two seperate indexes NOT one containing both lat and long.

Comment: GiST works extremely well. If you want to do more complex geospatial work, check out PostGIS, which provides some powerful data types and GiST index types for working with GIS.

Comment: This seems the closest to what I need.  I've created individual indexes on latitude and longitude and limited the scan range with +/- 0.5 degree on either direction; then I created a gist index; but what really cut the query time was this: instead of having `where` clause on the distance, I check the distance inside the loop (the query is inside a plpgsql function).  As the distance is one of the returned values and I'm also sorting by this distance, I simply abort the loop when I reach the required distance.

Comment: (continued) This is rather strange: immutable functions are supposed to be computed only once for each set of parameters, yet it seems like on each iteration they were computed multiple times: once for the returned value, once for the `where` clause and once for sorting.

Comment: The query analyzer has to recognise thatthe repetition is going to happen to take advantage of it, otherwise it'd waste more than it gains. Have you tried a partial index that indexes on lat and lng, but excludes rows where object_id is null? That seems even closer to what's wanted.

Comment: the given link is dead.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated. This is a link to chapter 4 of the GiST manual ("Using PostGIS: Data Management and Queries")

Answer (score 2):

Indices are not magical. The default index style is just a b-tree, that can be used to satisfy requests for `indexed_key = value`, `indexed_key < value` etc, but just creating one on a bunch of columns doesn't make any expression based on those column values immediately efficient.

Postgresql, as of 9.1, doesn't support using the index as a "covering index" to cut down on the amount of disk I/O necessary to do a full scan. 9.2 will. in the meantime, if you think that will be of benefit, use triggers to keep an auxiliary table populated, which is essentially the same thing, just without the sugar of having it automatically used from queries. But this doesn't change the fact that you'll be doing a bunch of trig calculations for each of 250,000 rows.

If you really want to do this sort of some geospatial indexing, use the cube/earthdistance extensions to build a GiST r-tree index on the coordinates. This will allow you to use an index lookup for queries of the form "find all points within this box", and then you can add the additional function criteria to trim out results that are in the box but outside your target sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Your query's other constraint is the result of a function, the only way to get that is to execute it for all non null values.

It would only be of some use if you could cut down the range of values that have to be calculated.

ie if you could calculate a min and max long and lat that were worth bothering to calculate.
Then you could beef up the constraint 
With

```
and (n_latitude between LaMin and LaMax) and (n_longitude between loMin and loMax)
```

Comment: I added a condition on the two - it cut the query time very slightly - from about 4 seconds to just about 3.5 seconds - but still it takes ages.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup and use the standard PostgreSQL type `point` for lat / lon. The following works with PostgreSQL 8.4+.

```
CREATE table object(
 object_id serial PRIMARY KEY
,geocode point
);
```

Then I add a GIST index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX object_geocode_idx
ON object
USING gist (box(geocode, geocode));
```

Note how I index a virtual **box**, formed by two points - the same two points in the case of the index.
In addition, I **cluster** my table on that index, so a minimum of blocks will have to be fetched.

```
ALTER TABLE object CLUSTER ON object_geocode_idx;
```

Now, try a search like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   object
WHERE  box(geocode,geocode) <@ box(mypoint1, mypoint2);
```

Read about the ["contained in" operator in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html).
Check with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` if the index gets used. If it is, the query should be lightening fast. Make that box just big enough to include all your points. Apply additional criteria if you want to get rid of the literal corner cases. This will be cheap.

Comment: The box wouldn't work very well, as the earth coordinate system is not a plain but on the surface of the sphere.  The distance between two points on a surface of a sphere isn't nearly the distance on a flat surface. As my data contains data points around the world and the distance measurements (limits) are sometimes quite large (up to a hundred of miles or more), the two values end up being quite far apart.

Comment: @AleksG: As long as the `given distance` of your search does not exceed a couple of 100 km and your results do not have to be precise, this approach is fast and good enough. For anything more I would turn to PostGis as has been mentioned here before.

Comment: @ErwinBrandsetter: Unfortunately, we've had complaints from some of our clients of sort "it's only 15 miles between us and point x, not 19 as shown on your site".  Therefore we needed to get the much more precise function for computing the geo_distance (with all the trigs in it) - it gives results with only about a mile error over 2,000 miles distance.

Comment: @AleksG: For 15 miles the curvature of the earth is practically irrelevant. You must have an error of a different kind in your calculation.

Comment: I was exaggerating. With the current function for computing the distance we get a pretty good approximation; I am (and more importantly - the client is) happy with the results.  I'm just trying to find the best way to query objects by location.  Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: @AleksG: My answer **is** about querying objects by location. The point here is to retrieve a small set out of huge one, and *then* calculate the exact distance. You do not want to calculate the distance for all 250.000 rows, this is way too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a function based index:

```
create index idx_object_distance on objects(fn_geo_distance(51.5, 0, n_latitude, n_longitude))
```

**Update**

like Tony Hopkinson suggested, the other option you have is to use **between** to filter the ranges

You would need two separate indexes to make that happen fast:

```
create index idx_object_latitude on objects(n_latitude);
create index idx_object_longitude on objects(n_longitude);
```

the database would scan both indexes and the do a merge join on the results

Comment: I can't do that, as the two params `51.5` and `0` are the variables in my case

Comment: +1 for your username and avatar, the answer is not helping though ;)